# How can I create an expression that evaluates whether or not a parent div's descendants are active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, expression

Imagine I have a div with a few descendants/children as such:

```
<div id="parent" tabindex="0">
  <h1 tabindex="0"> my Header </h1>
  <p tabindex="0"> some text </p>
  <ul tabindex="0">
     <li tabindex="0"> item 1 </li>
     <li tabindex="0"> item 2 </li>
     <li tabindex="0"> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I create an expression that checks whether or not a child of the 'parent' div is active/has focus? I'd like to perform some action (ex: console log) if the statement evaluates to true.

I'd imagine it's go something like:

```
if( document.activeelement === <descendant of 'parent' div>) {
     console.log("descendant is active"); 
  }
```

EDIT: For clarity: 
The evaluation should occur as an *'if' statement*. The expression should translate like so:

**if my active element has a parent with an id of 'parent' then do something.**

Comment: Under what context? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MikeC I'm not quite sure the syntax to create the expression, my thought process is included above

Comment: If you're using jQuery, have you looked into the [`:focus` selector?](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) How about the [`.parents()` method?](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) If you know how to query the DOM using jQuery and can understand these two functions, the answer will jump out at you.

Comment: When should check occur?

Comment: I have added an edit for clarification

Answer (score 0):

do you know the id of the parent and the classnames of the children? or will these be dynamic based on what is clicked? if you know the selector of the parent and children, the following will grab an `li` element that is a deep or immediate child of the `#parent` element that is active. if it is empty, then none of those tabs are focused

```
$(#parent li:focus)
```

using this jquery selector, we're asking for any `li` child of the `#parent` element that is active (`:focus`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click`, `keydown`, `keyuyp` events attached to `document`, `$("#parent [tabindex]")` selector, `.is()` , `:focus`

```js
function checkFocus() {
  console.log("descendant is active:"
              , $("#parent [tabindex]").is(":focus")
              , this.activeElement.tagName)
}

$(document).on("click keydown keyup", checkFocus)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" tabindex="0">
  <h1 tabindex="0"> my Header </h1>
  <p tabindex="0">some text</p>
  <ul tabindex="0">
    <li tabindex="0">item 1</li>
    <li tabindex="0">item 2</li>
    <li tabindex="0">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```